# Ошибка "... supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource ..."

Tags: php, mysql

Что я неправильно сделал?

```
<?php
$bd = mysql_connect("localhost", "david", "1111");
mysql_select_db("feikdom", $bd);
$rezult = mysql_query(" SELECT title , meta_d , meta_q ,text FROM  settings WHERE page = 'index' ", $db);
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($rezult);
?>
```

Хотел подключится к базе и вытащить поля `title`, `meta_d`, `meta_q`, `text`. 'Выводит такие ошибки:

> `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in Z:\home\Java.ru\www\index.php on line 4`
>
> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\Java.ru\www\index.php on line 5'`

Comment: @Котля Заголовок вопроса должен отражать суть проблемы и не должен содержать орфографических ошибок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$bd и $db разные переменные :)

Comment: Я тя люблю !

Comment: Слева от ответа есть галочка "Люблю". Отметьте, пожалуйста. =)

Comment: Ахахахахахахахахахах, а @Котля девочка или мальчик?